# Issue with combobox and concurrency in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, concurrency

I have a following issue. I have a `CombBox` which should display names of my `Quiz` class (this class has furthemore a list of `Tasks`) and I want to remove every single `Quiz` from the available selection. I also have the `Quizzes` separated by the `Teacher` who created them, and I only want to display the according `Quizzes` to the selected owner in the 2nd `ComboBox` (I had no issues with this part so far).

Here's my code.

QuizComboBox

```
public class QuizComboBox extends ComboBox {

public QuizComboBox() {
    List<Quiz> quizList = new QuizDao().getAllQuizes();

    startTask(quizList);

    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Quiz>, ListCell<Quiz>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<Quiz> call(ListView<Quiz> arg0) {
                return new ListCell<Quiz>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Quiz item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        if (item == null || empty) {
                            setGraphic(null);
                        } else {
                            String quizText = item.getName();
                            setText(quizText);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });
    });
}

public void startTask(List<Quiz> quizList){
    Runnable task = () -> removeEmptyQuizzes(quizList);
    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(task);
    backgroundThread.setDaemon(true);
    backgroundThread.start();
}

private void removeEmptyQuizzes(List<Quiz> quizList){
    for(Quiz q : quizList){
        if(q.getTaskList().isEmpty()){
            quizList.remove(q);
        }
    }
    Platform.runLater(() -> setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(quizList)));
}
```

}

Here's the listener of the `ComboBox` with `Teachers` which updates the items

```
    private void teacherComboBoxListener(){
    view.getTeacherComboBox().getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Teacher>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Teacher> arg0, Teacher oldValue, Teacher newValue) {

            view.getQuizComboBox().setValue(null);

            if(newValue == view.getAllTeachersChoice()){
                List<Quiz> quizList = new QuizDao().getAllQuizes();
                view.getQuizComboBox().startTask(quizList);
            }
            else {
                Teacher selectedTeacher = (Teacher) view.getTeacherComboBox().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                List<Quiz> quizList = selectedTeacher.getQuizList();
                view.getQuizComboBox().startTask(quizList);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I'm getting the following exception

```
  Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at view.controlElements.QuizComboBox.removeEmptyQuizzes(QuizComboBox.java:51)
    at view.controlElements.QuizComboBox.lambda$startTask$1(QuizComboBox.java:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

EDIT: I've tried @fabian's solution and it works with quite a big bug, it removes all the `Quizzez` with empty `TaskList` from my database.

```
    private void removeEmptyQuizzes(List<Quiz> quizList){
    for(Iterator<Quiz> iterator = quizList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
        Quiz q = iterator.next();
        if(q.getTaskList().isEmpty()){
            iterator.remove(); // removed from db also
        }
    }
    Platform.runLater(() -> setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(quizList)));
}
```

Comment: @fabian Hm, it indeed works now, however, it creates also quite a big bug. It removes all Quizzes with empty TaskList from my database as well.

Comment: @fabian I edited the question if you want to take a look

Comment: You need to explain in detail why removing the empty quizzes as stated in the question is a problem. "It removes all the quizzes with empty task list from my database" is a statement noone can verify. All we see is a list from which items are removed. It would be really strange if that also affected persistent storage.